# inputmask not working when input clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-inputmask

I have included the inputmask js files correctly and can see it in my source.

in my app.js I have the following along with my HTML in my view however I am getting nothing when I click the input why?

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(":input").inputmask();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for=
                "dob">D.O.B</label>

                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input class="form-control" data-inputmask=
                    "'alias': 'dd/mm/yyyy'" type="text">
                </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it in a `click` function?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".form-group > div > input").on('click', function(){
     $(this).inputmask();
  });
});
```

**OR**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".form-group > div > input").on('click', inputmask());
});
```

Comment: second one gives me inputmask not defined,  still no luck with the other and its working as i chucked in an alert and it fired

Comment: what order are you calling your scripts in the html file?

Comment: im using a "builder" as such so the inputmask is first then my code